# Reduce keeps restarting to 0% without any failure

Tags: hive

I am running a MapReduce job but the reduce task always restarts at 0% without any failure. I can't find anything related to this on the web. Any help?

> 2016-06-02 07:19:33,992 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 21%, Cumulative
>   CPU 36280.53 sec 2016-06-02 07:19:49,351 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce =
>   22%, Cumulative CPU 36288.54 sec 2016-06-02 07:20:29,331 Stage-1 map =
>   100%,  reduce = 23%, Cumulative CPU 36309.57 sec 2016-06-02
>   07:20:41,626 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 24%, Cumulative CPU
>   36316.05 sec 2016-06-02 07:20:50,847 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 25%, Cumulative CPU 36320.83 sec 2016-06-02 07:21:09,279 Stage-1 map =
>   100%,  reduce = 27%, Cumulative CPU 36330.34 sec 2016-06-02
>   07:21:21,598 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 28%, Cumulative CPU
>   36336.66 sec 2016-06-02 07:21:33,898 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 29%, Cumulative CPU 36342.98 sec 2016-06-02 07:21:52,330 Stage-1 map =
>   100%,  reduce = 30%, Cumulative CPU 36352.47 sec 2016-06-02
>   07:22:10,764 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 31%, Cumulative CPU
>   36361.88 sec
>   **2016-06-02 07:22:19,996 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 32%, Cumulative CPU 36366.42 sec 2016-06-02 07:22:28,216 Stage-1 map =
>   100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 36053.06 sec** 2016-06-02
>   07:22:40,576 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 1%, Cumulative CPU 36062.98
>   sec 2016-06-02 07:22:49,795 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 2%,
>   Cumulative CPU 36070.63 sec 2016-06-02 07:23:14,373 Stage-1 map =
>   100%,  reduce = 3%, Cumulative CPU 36086.48 sec 2016-06-02
>   07:23:54,361 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 4%, Cumulative CPU 36108.05
>   sec

Comment: how many times it restarts ? it think it fails after 3 times

Comment: how many mappers and reducers are being spawned? please post a sample of your SQL and any configuration settings you are setting manually.

Comment: *"without any failure"* -- did you check the YARN logs for the `job_00000_0000000` identifier that you can find in Hive log? *(just remember to replace the deprecated `job_` prefix with `application_` when searching the YARN UI or YARN command-line)*. You will probably find some OOM error that caused an execution failure, with auto-retry by the AppMaster until it hits the max number of failed attempts.